# How to make a mini fab in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button

In XML we can make the floating action button in 2 sizes (regular and [mini](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#mini-fabs)) like the following

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
  ...
  app:fabSize="mini"/>
```

My Question is how to make mini fab in `Compose` as the `FloatingActionButton` implementation as the follow (with no parameter for the size)

```
@Composable
fun FloatingActionButton(
    onClick: (() -> Unit)?,
    modifier: Modifier! = Modifier,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource! = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape! = MaterialTheme.shapes.small.copy(CornerSize(percent = 50)),
    backgroundColor: Color! = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
    contentColor: Color! = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: FloatingActionButtonElevation! = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    content: (@Composable () -> Unit)?
): Unit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the FAB implementation it sets a default size.
If you want to change the FAB size, I think the only way is using the `Modifier.size(40.dp)`.

```
FloatingActionButton(
    modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp), // 40 is a mini-fab
    onClick = {  }
) {
    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = null)
}
```

Comment: That is something at least should be in `FloatingActionButtonDefaults`

Answer (score 4):

If you use `androidx.compose.material3` in your project, you can use `SmallFloatingActionButton`

```
@Composable
public fun SmallFloatingActionButton(
    onClick: () → Unit,
    modifier: Modifier,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource,
    shape: Shape,
    containerColor: Color,
    contentColor: Color,
    elevation: FloatingActionButtonElevation,
    content: @Composable
() → Unit
): Unit
```

Comment: Right, but material 3 is still alpha in compose, and I don't think that's good to change the whole theme to just make a mini fab

Answer (score 0):

In Compose, you can now use `SmallFloatingActionButton` using Material 3: example:

```
@Composable
fun SmallExample(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    SmallFloatingActionButton(
        onClick = { onClick() },
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "Example test")
    }
}
```

You can find out more on: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/fab#small